# Files on hard disk no longer show but disk space is still taken up, how can I make the files accessible again

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a computer running ubuntu server which I used as a media server.  Today after copying some files over to the drive in the server the files no longer show up on the HDD.  If I run the command

```
df -h
```

The drive still shows in the system with the correct amount of used and available disk space (about 1.6 TB used and 136 GB free), so am I correct in assuming the files are still there but for some reason have somehow been hidden?

This problem occurred after I was trying to determine why a second (newer HDD 3 TB) was not being detected by Ubuntu when running the above command as well.

In short I do not know why the files on the HDD have suddenly stopped being visible and I am not sure how I can get them back.

Comment: First, do `du -hs` and check if that reports 1.6 Tb as used. If it does, find the lost files with the `find` command, based on whatever you know about them: parts of the file name, its size, or date of creation. See `man find` and google for examples. Find the largest directories  with `du -h | sort -h`.

Comment: When I enter     du -hs I get the following output: 1.6T       .

Comment: For some reason I have found them all in a hidden folder on the drive called .AppleDouble.  No idea why they suddenly went into this folder or why this folder even exists, but thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure those files are not in Trash folder? What is your filesystem? And, finally, `du` lies a lot.

Comment: Yeah, see comments above.  I moved all the files back out of the .AppleDouble folder and its fine.  No idea how that happened though or why a .AppleDouble folder even existed.